# How to disable Configurable products and Downloadable products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, configurable-product, downloadable

There are two sections when I add a simple product and I'd like to disable or at least hide those.
"Configurations" and "Downloadable Information".

I know about Magento module:disable command and I'm aware of dependencies but I can't disable due I have a custom module and it breaks when I try to do.

Is there any other way to disable or hide as those aren't required fields?

Thank you

Comment: what u mean `There are two sections when i add a simple products and i'd like to disable or at least hide thoose. "Configurations" and "Downloadable Information".` i am not clear about this

Comment: can you check the screenshot?

https://ctrlv.cz/en/gJQh
or
https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2017/01/04/gJQh.png

Comment: none of these answers actually solve your problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i remove product tab in admin magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219085/how-can-i-remove-product-tab-in-admin-magento-2)

Answer (score 1):

As of Magento 2.2 the admin System Configuration Panel "Advanced" has been removed.

The following gives reference on how to disable a module's output.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/config/disable-module-output.html

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **store->configurations->adavanced->advanced**

disable those modules from there. This will only suppress output of those modules unlike `module:disable` command. It will essentially hide all thHTMLml output from those modules.