# How can i remove product tab in admin magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent, ui

I want to remove configuration, design, search engine optimization tab. any have idea how it done? 
 [image]

Answer (score 3):

You can hide these tabs ( configuration, design, search engine optimization) by using following code in ui_component xml.

> app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="configurable">
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
       </item>
     </argument>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset name="design">
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
       </item>
     </argument>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset name="search-engine-optimization">
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
       </item>
     </argument>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

There is no fieldset option to remove fieldset tab. You can [check here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-fieldset.html) for more details regarding fieldset options.

Cheers !!!

Comment: My pleasure and good luck to you in your endeavors! You can accept this answer too.